# How to return a XML file with Spring MVC?

Tags: java, xml, ajax, spring-mvc

I have this method:

```
@RequestMapping( value = DetailedMetaDataController.RESOURCE_PATH + ".xml", headers = "Accept=application/json" )
public void exportXml( @RequestBody JSONObject json ) throws IOException
{
    String responseString = JacksonUtils.toXmlAsString();
}
```

The `responseString` is a XML String. The AJAX request is a post because I send large amount of data, but the AJAX always returns error.

I need a simple Window with which to save the String as a xml file.

Comment: Can you post the error, status code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotate with `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)` and make sure your request uses `application/xml` as part of an `Accept` header.

Comment: I don't think this is JAX-RS.

Comment: JAX-RS is part of JRE6 core, and Jackson is designed to be used with JAX-RS, so I assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that this was a jax-rs project.

Comment: With `@RequestMapping`, it's a Spring MVC project, which also uses jackson. OP might want to consider using JSX-RS.

Comment: Can you help me with a fix for a Spring MVC project ?. I have the string ready, just cant figure out how to send it as a xml file :(

Comment: You'll get no help from me with Spring MVC. Sorry.  You might want to add Spring MVC to your tag list.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the data in a bean annotated with `@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement`, field with `@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement` and change method signature from `public void` to `public @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody BeanClassName`, returning corresponding `BeanClassName` instance. Also remember about `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in your Spring XML config file.

For more info see [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-xml-example/).